Multivariate gaussian integral with squared quadratic term outside exponent
I have found a post in 1, but can't solve the integral
\begin{align}
\int(x^{T}Rx)^{2}\exp\big[-\frac{1}{2}(x^{T}Ax)\big]dx,
\end{align}
with $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and PD matrices $A,R \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, could someone give me any hints?
I tried with a simple case with $n=2$. Since
\begin{align}
x^{T}Rx = r_{11}x_{1} + r_{21}x_{1}x_{2} + r_{12}x_{1}x_{2} + r_{22}x_{2}, 
\end{align}
and using the fact that only even function survives after the integral due to symmetric structure, I can see that I need to consider these terms
\begin{align}
&\text{tems needs to consider in }(x^{T}Rx)^{2}\\
&= r_{11}^{2}x_{1}^{4} + r_{22}^{2}x_{2}^{4} + (r_{12}^{2}+r_{21}^{2}+2{r_{12}r_{21}}+ 2r_{11}r_{22})x_{1}^{2}x_{2}^{2}.
\end{align}
My question is how I can write these weighting with $R$ in a nice way using maybe trace and matrix multiplication.
Thank you.

I suggest you add your attempts as well as context to avoid having your question closed. Your integrand is composed of $x_i^2 x_j^2$ against the Gaussian measure...
